# What is actual path for css file in javaFx application?

Tags: javafx

I wan to know, what is actual path for css file in javafx application???
i am trying to understand the structure but sometimes getting confusion..
relevant answers from experts.
and most importantly guys suggest me good practices of javafx.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate see the Eden tutorial: [Where to put resource files in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/)

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

The files you store in your project will be put on the classpath when creating a JAR.

**Solution:**

Put the CSS files into the ressources folder into a folder called CSS.

ressources/css/file.css

You can access them e.g. with an absolute path from classpath like this:

`getClass().getResource("/css/file.css")`.

Instead of using `getClass()` you can use `YourClass.class` too.

**Other example:**

Consider your CSS file is placed in:

ressources/your/group/id/css/file.css

Then you can access like this:

`getClass().getResource("/your/group/id/css/file.css")`